# Is a graphical document author/designer interface realizable with LaTeX3?

Tags: latex3, latex-misc

With the separation of document authorship, design, and implementation, is a graphical tool for the end-user within reach?

LyX tries to do this today, but LaTeX2e is not well-designed for such an approach.
In essence, this is what LaTeX3 tries to fix:
  authors must not be concerned with how their document looks
  in contest with the actual content of their work.
While LaTeX2e did successfully separate markup from implementation,
  it could not cleanly separate the *design* from its implementation
  (and everyone and their mother has a word to say about design—this isn't going to change).
The layers of LaTeX3 are designed to separate
  the implementation/coding from the design from the content.
The amazing work so far on LaTeX3 is proof enough that
  many people believe this separation is possible—myself included.

Given this ideal of separation, will it be feasible for there to be environments in which to author and design LaTeX documents in a way that will put the power of LaTeX and `expl3` in high demand?

Comment: I'm worried this looks rather like a discussion topic, and also depends on what the team _want_ to do rather than what they _have_ done. Better suited to LaTeX-L?

Comment: @JosephWright Sure thing—I didn't think about that.  What the team *wants* to do probably/realistically won't be static over time :-) I'll send an email out shortly…

Comment: I would probably want to record my thoughts around that topic - we have similar questions where I have given answers about the ideas that have been developed over time in that space

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX is about *contents*, not micromanagement of squiggles on paper. In a sense, such an idea goes directly against LaTeX' advantages. A collection of LaTeX advocacy papers in this line is [here](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/Typesetting/TeX/LaTeX/Advocacy). I'm against Lyx and such precisely because it's users write horrible source that happens to look nice (Same as MS Office, BTW: the document looks nice, but its internal structure is a complete mess, as nobody looks at that. Good luck doing any restructuring on it!). If you then need to integrate this in something else (make it a chapter in a book, for example) or reformat it to some random journal's taste, you'll be in a world of hurt.

If you want to do graphics layout, other tools are a better fit.

Comment: I don't agree with the intro. It is those micromanagers that separates boys from men. Otherwise MS Word is pretty if you don't mind those kerning, linespread, justification etc.

Comment: I'm also pretty strongly against LyX (and have been since I started using LaTeX directly around 2011), but that's not what the idea is about. Authors *shouldn't* be concerned even with the implementation of the semantics -- just the semantics themselves. There is no need to see, say, `\AlgorithmName` as part of the running text. This information should certainly exist and be easily accessible, but part of the running text? I'm not so sure.